# Problemas de CORS entre aplicación y API en mismo servidor

Tags: nodejs, angular, iis

Tengo una aplicación y un API en el mismo servidor (Angular 2+ y NodeJs con Express). La aplicación está corriendo en un IIS 10.

El caso es que yo, desde ese servidor, accedo perfectamente a la aplicación web usando `http://localhost` y desde ésta al API.

El problema es cuando intento acceder desde el exterior. Cuando se realiza la petición al API se ve esto:

[image: Registro de petición OPTIONS]

En principio creo que no debería de existir ningún problema, pero ¿a qué `192.168.0.14:800` está intentando acceder?

Se supone que debería tratarse de forma interna y que la aplicación haga sus tratos con el API del mismo equipo. ¿No?

En Firefox por ejemplo me da el siguiente error de CORS:

[image: Error de CORS en Firefox]

En Google Chrome me arroja este error:

[image: Error en Chrome]

Comment: Cuando dices "yo desde ese servidor accedo perfectamente a la aplicación web" te refieres a entrar usando http://localhost? En ese caso debes saber que las reglas CORS se relajan, pero dos páginas alojadas en la misma IP pero con diferentes puertos [no cumplen las reglas de CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Además, debes de tener en cuenta que tengas accesible el puerto 800 desde el exterior. El mensaje de chrome es una conexión que no llega a establecerse, probablemente, por culpa de un cortafuegos que filtra la conexión.

Comment: Si, me refiero estando en el servidor y utilizando el explorador desde localhost. Puede que el firewall esté bloquenado las conexiones por ese puerto. ¿ De todas formas, porque habla de CORS? Intentaré cambiar la configuración del IIS a ver si es por eso.

Comment: Te puse un enlace en el primer comentario, pero vuelvo a ponerte el enlace aquí: [https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Léetelo porque necesitarás preparar tu aplicación para que responda y ofrezca ciertas cabeceras HTTP para permitir el acceso cruzado.

Comment: El. *Connection time out* hace pensar que está ocurriendo un bloqueo en alguna parte. Si revisa el log de errores en el servidor encontrarás respuestas más precisas de lo que está ocurriendo.

Comment: app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://192.168.0.14' , credentials :  true})); o 
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' , credentials :  true}));

Comment: He estado probando y configurando el CORS. El caso es que por lo visto, si la app apunta a localhost:3000 (por ejemplo) o 192.168.0.14:3000 lo que hace es buscar en mi red local o mi equipo en vez de tomar como 192.168.0.14 de la red en la que se encuentra el servidor que aloja la web. Con lo cual deduzco que habrá que utilizar la ip externa del servidor o algo así.

Comment: Deberías darnos más información de qué está corriendo en qué puerto y si la dirección IP que estás accediendo es la del servidor desde la red local o desde Internet, etc.

Comment: En cuanto al puerto he cambiado varias veces para diferentes pruebas. De todas formas ahora mismo el servicio esta corriendo en el puerto 3000, y la aplicación angular en el 4200. La dirección IP a la que accede esa aplicación de Angular es la 192.168.0.14, que es la ip del servidor. Cuando estoy en el servidor todo funciona, ya que encuentra la IP. Pero cuando yo la abro desde un ordenador cualquiera sigue yendo a esa 192.168.0.14, y en mi red no la encuentra. Con lo cual me supongo que sería necesario poner como IP de acceso al API la Ipo externa de servidor.

Comment: Ya está resuleto, puedo verlo desde fuera, pero ahora existe otro problema. El caso es que los puertos no estaban abiertos correctamente y ahora todo funciona con normalidad si lo hacers desde fuera de la red. El problema es que si accedes a la aplicación desde dentro de la red donde está alojada la máquina que sirve esa aplicación da error de CORS, ya que intenta acceder mediante la ip publica. ¿De que manera podría saber si la llamada es desde dentro de la red o desde fuera? De esta forma darle un valor diferente a la dirección a la que se va a acceder.

Comment: Sea con IP local o con IP externa el problema de CORS ha estado ahí desde el principio. Deberías proporcionarnos la información que te solicitamos en su momento o crear una pregunta nueva con la información necesaria para poder ayudarte. Recuerda que el funcionamiento de cómo está todo montado está en tu cabeza y no en la nuestra. Necesitamos conocer los detalles para poder ayudate.